# NullPointerExceptions in Youtube API

Tags: java, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

I am currently trying to learn how to use the Youtube APIs and stuff, but I am getting a few NullPointerException Errors, and I just cant figure out why...

I already tried everything I could find in the Documentation, but nothing changed.

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API code samples";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/**
 * Create an authorized Credential object.
 *
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = CreateBroadcast.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
      GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .build();
    Credential credential =
        new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized API client service.
 *
 * @return an authorized API client service
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
 */
public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
    return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
}

/**
 * Call function to create API service object. Define and
 * execute API request. Print API response.
 *
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
    YouTube youtubeService = getService();
    
    // Define the LiveBroadcast object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
    LiveBroadcast liveBroadcast = new LiveBroadcast();
    
    // Add the contentDetails object property to the LiveBroadcast object.
    LiveBroadcastContentDetails contentDetails = new LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
    contentDetails.setEnableClosedCaptions(true);
    contentDetails.setEnableContentEncryption(true);
    contentDetails.setEnableDvr(true);
    contentDetails.setEnableEmbed(true);
    contentDetails.setRecordFromStart(true);
    contentDetails.setStartWithSlate(true);
    liveBroadcast.setContentDetails(contentDetails);
    
    // Add the snippet object property to the LiveBroadcast object.
    LiveBroadcastSnippet snippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    snippet.setScheduledStartTime(new DateTime("2024-01-30T00:00:00.000Z"));
    snippet.setTitle("Test broadcast");
    liveBroadcast.setSnippet(snippet);
    
    // Add the status object property to the LiveBroadcast object.
    LiveBroadcastStatus status = new LiveBroadcastStatus();
    status.setPrivacyStatus("unlisted");
    liveBroadcast.setStatus(status);

    // Define and execute the API request
    YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Insert request = youtubeService.liveBroadcasts()
        .insert("snippet,contentDetails,status", liveBroadcast);
    LiveBroadcast response = request.execute();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

And these are the Errors I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.live.CreateBroadcast.authorize(CreateBroadcast.java:47)
at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.live.CreateBroadcast.getService(CreateBroadcast.java:65)
at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.live.CreateBroadcast.main(CreateBroadcast.java:79)
```

I am very sorry if this is a stupid question :)
Thanks in advance, Thilo

Comment: Could you please add the whole exception stacktrace?

Comment: Where are you initializing CLIENT_SECRETS?  Check that it can access the client secret file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the YouTube API.

`CreateBroadcast.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS)` is returning null, [as the documentation states it will](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), because CLIENT_SECRETS does not contain a resource URL that points an existing resource.

Note that it *must* be a relative URL, not a file path.  A relative URL means a path with a forward slashes (`/`), on all platforms.

If you are running from a .jar file, you can simply verify that the .jar file contains the resource you are requesting:

- If CLIENT_SECRETS starts with an initial slash, it is relative to the root of the .jar file.  Meaning, if CLIENT_SECRETS is `"/config/secrets.txt"`, your .jar file needs to contain a `config/secrets.txt` entry.
- If CLIENT_SECRETS does not start with an initial slash, it is relative to the package of the CreateBroadcast class.  Meaning, if CLIENT_SECRETS is `"secrets.txt"`, the .jar file needs to contain a `com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/live/secrets.txt` entry.

If you are not running from a .jar file, the same rules apply, but you need to check every directory in your runtime classpath which was added by your IDE.  Many IDEs will conform to Maven conventions and will just use the target/classes subdirectory in the project.

In all cases, if the value of CLIENT_SECRETS is not the path of an existing resource, the getResourceAsStream method returns null.  You are then passing that null to `new InputStreamReader`, which is the cause of your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `CLIENT_SECRETS` resource cannot be found and `CreateBroadcast.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS)` returns `null`. Call to `new InputStreamReader(in)` with `null` in the next line ends up with the NPE.